# How to start a slideshow without music in applescript?

Tags: applescript, slideshow, photos

Currently I am using this applescript to start a slideshow:

```
set theAlbumName to "Test"
tell application "Photos"
      start slideshow using media items of album theAlbumName
end tell
```

However, no matter what I do, there is always music when the slide show starts.
There are videos in my slide show and I do not want music playing over them.
Is there any way to **NOT have music**, or change the music to something different (an empty sound file?) **when you call it from the applescript**?

I have tried deleting the project's music, but when I call the slideshow from applescript, there is still music.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no Applescript command to remove music. The work around is to create your slideshow via the menu, and during creation, select music on right side of the screen, then select "Themes songs" instead of "iTunes" and  unclick the selected theme. Save your slideshow. Any next time you will play it, it will no longer contains music (except your movies). I never found a way to run, by script, the created slideshow ! I must run it directly.

Comment: How about settings the device to mute on start? You could applescript that easily. Would that work for you?